# Identify this Indian movie about someone reporting his well being stolen

Tags: identify-this-movie

An Indian taxi driver told me about this movie, but I forgot the movie name

I found the plot to be very interesting. It is an Indian movie, about someone who report his well being stolen. The entire village being bribed to confirm that this guy had a well but lost it in the following morning.

I would like to watch it but can't find any clue from Google.

What is the name of this movie?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Must be [Well done Abba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_Done_Abba).

On seeing the words *well* and *stolen*. That's the first one that came to my mind.

Though the well being stolen isn't the crux of the story, its a part of it.

It's a Hindi movie.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is Marathi movie with same story. The movie is 'Jau Tithe Khau', starring Makarand Anaspure and Deepali Sayyad...

Mukund (Makarand Anaspure) is hard working and intelligent young man, who is unable to find a job. He faces a lot of issues in his day to day life for the things which he has to depend on. Every public officer he meets like at electricity board, pension office etc. ask him for bribe to carry out the work. Enraged by this behavior and the corrupt political system he decides to fight against the system. He is helped by his girlfriend Lekha (Deepali Syed) and few friends. Based upon this help he applies for a government scheme in which the person is entitled for loan approval on getting a well dug. By bribing all the officers in the loop, he manages to get the loan approved without even digging the well.
At the climax he files a case in the police station and court about his well getting stolen. At first he is held as madman, as a well, a solid structure can't be stolen. But then Mukund presents the proofs on the paper about the well being dug. The court has to accept the proof and declare that the well was indeed stolen. Mukund wins the Lawsuit.
However Mukund rejects the decision by himself and explain the people the real situation and warns them about the current state of corruption in the country. The film ends on the note that 'Today a well is proven to be stolen, Don't let the country to be proved stolen" as addressed by Mukund to the people.

**Jau Tithe Khau was remade in Hindi as Well Done Abba.**

Comment: Could you add a synopsis of the movie you think it may be?

Answer (score 4):

it is a tamil movie, kannum kannum

Comment: Unless this is a different translation for the title of the movie from the already accepted answer, this either isn't correct, or you're posting the same answer as the already accepted one.

Comment: @MattD It is altogether a different movie from the one accepted as answer. This scene also has the same sequence as OP posted. The comedian reports to the police about his well being stolen :D

Comment: @MattD In India , we have movies in different languages or states. Now, it is becoming common to remake same movie with different language with almost same sequence. Only difference everyone uses actors from their state :-) .

Answer (score -1):

The name of the movie is Saluun.
But i think the movie did not release at the box office due to some reasons.
Moreover i could not even find it online also.

Comment: Please add what makes you think this is the correct answer.

Comment: "Due to some reasons" isn't exactly a phrase brimming with information, either.